# Different colors for same function Plot

Tags: plotting, map

I created a list with coefficients to be used in various `Sin` functions

```
Map[(#*Pi/5)&,Subdivide[3.5,15,4]]
```

> {2.19911,4.00553,5.81195,7.61836,9.42478}

It can be observed that the values ​​of the list above were inserted manually in the function below:

```
Plot[{50 Sin[2.19911 x], 50 Sin[4.00553 x], 50 Sin[5.81195 x],50 Sin[7.61836 x], 50 Sin[9.42478 x]}, {x, 0, 10},
 AxesLabel -> {"Time [Second]", "Angle [Degree]"},
 PlotLabel -> "Angle x Time",
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

I tried to insert these coefficients using `Map` function. The result is correct, but the colors did not vary.

What should I call in the function for the colors to be different?

```
Show[Plot[{50 Sin[# x]}, {x, 0, 10}] & /@ Map[(#*Pi/5) &, Subdivide[3.5, 15, 4]],
 AxesLabel -> {"Time [Second]", "Angle [Degree]"},
 PlotLabel -> "Angle x Time",
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Plot[Evaluate[{50 Sin[# x]} & /@ Map[(#*Pi/5) &, Subdivide[3.5, 15,4]]], {x, 0, 10},
     AxesLabel -> {"Time [Second]", "Angle [Degree]"}, 
     PlotLabel -> "Angle x Time", ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, if you have to use `Show`, you can get the same picture by `Style`ing each function with a different color:

```
i=1;
Show[Plot[Style[50 Sin[# x], ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[i++]]], {x, 0, 10}   ] & /@ 
 Map[(#*Pi/5) &, Subdivide[3.5, 15, 4]],
 AxesLabel -> {"Time [Second]", "Angle [Degree]"},
 PlotLabel -> "Angle x Time",
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can exploit the fact that [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times.html), [`Divide`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Divide.html), and [`Sin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sin.html) are all [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html)

```
Attributes /@ {Times, Divide, Sin}

(*  {{Flat, Listable, NumericFunction, OneIdentity, Orderless, 
  Protected}, {Listable, NumericFunction, Protected}, {Listable, 
  NumericFunction, Protected}}  *)
```

The [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) then simplifies to

```
Plot[Evaluate[50 Sin[Subdivide[3.5, 15, 4] Pi/5 x]], {x, 0, 10}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Time [Second]", "Angle [Degree]"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Angle x Time", ImageSize -> Large]
```